# Installed Ubuntu 14.10, and nothing works

Tags: gnome, gui, interface, 14.10

I've installed it on my old Acer Aspire 6530 from an USB.

But I have not interface, or what to say. There is no menu to the left, there is no top bar with information (Wifi, battery and such) and possibly even more important.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Some specs:
CPU: AMD Turion X2
GPU: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3560
RAM: 4GB

EDIT: I can now access the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Once you are booted up to the blank desktop... press CTRL + ALT + F1.

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime

shutdown -r now
```

**(or)**

Try switching the terminal (CTRL+ALT+F1) and then remove the configuration file ~/.config/dconf/user like this :

(this action will remove your gnome 3 settings)

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using an AMD GPU, so will nvidia work?

Comment: @ZackKlockar No it will not. This answer will not apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove your driver and reinstall

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

**Note: ignore any errors you may have got form running the first 2 commands.**

Remove your xorg.conf file

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Re-install xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

**Reboot:**

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, I was not able to locate nearly any of the packages.